# syntax error near unexpected token `if'

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, if-statement, scripting

I am currently trying to write a bash script which helps me step through a directory and check for .jpeg or .jpg extensions on files. I've come up with the following:

```
#declare $PICPATH, etc...

for file in $PICPATH
    if [ ${file -5} == ".jpeg" -o ${file -4} == ".jpg" ];
    then
        #do some exif related stuff here.
    else
        #throw some errors
    fi
done
```

Upon execution, bash keeps throwing a an error on the if line: "syntax error near unexpected token `if'.

I'm a completely new to scripting; what is wrong with my if statement?

Thanks.

Comment: To remove the last 5 characters of a variable use `${file::-5}`, what you are doing `${file -5}` won't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're just missing the do clause of the `for` loop:

```
#declare $PICPATH, etc...

for file in $PICPATH; do
    if [ ${file -5} == ".jpeg" -o ${file -4} == ".jpg" ];
    then
        #do some exif related stuff here.
    else
        #throw some errors
    fi
done
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I spent an hour trying to figure out what went wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can put the `do` on a new line if you prefer it. Then, you can omit the semicolon `;` before it. The same applies to the `then` after the `if`.

Answer (score 2):

```
${file -5}
```

is a syntax error. Maybe you mean

```
${file#*.}
```

?

Anyway, better do :

```
for file in $PICPATH; do
    image_type="$(file -i "$file" | awk '{print gensub(";", "", $2)}')"
    case $image_type in
        image/jpeg)
            # do something with jpg "$file"
        ;;
        image/png)
            # do something with png "$file"
        ;;
        *)
            echo >&2 "not implemented $image_type type "
            exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
```

If you only want to treat `jpg` files, do :

```
for file in $PICPATH; do
    image_type="$(file -i "$file" | awk '{print gensub(";", "", $2)}')"
    if [[ $image_type == image/jpeg ]]; then
            # do something with jpg "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the improved version, but I only need the case for jpeg: everything else should be ignored. Thanks a lot for the response anyways.